# htaccess redirect with parameters not working correctly

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

hope you can help me. i need a redirect from

```
/abc_company_detail.php?id=4 to detail/4/
```

So when I call the URL http://mydomain.com/abc_company_detail.php?id=4 then I got this pretty URL http://mydomain.com/detail/4/

Comment: pls post your .htaccess file contain, i think u r doing in reverse order mapping should be from detail/4/ to /abc_company_detail.php?id=4

Answer (score 0):

You can use some PHP framework, and it will managed the URL for you. If you want to do it manually you have to configure .htacess file.

Try this link. [.htaccess friendly URl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12538466/htaccess-friendly-url)
This kind of question had been asked before.