# .htaccess remove index.php and others from url

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a problem whereby google has indexed some pages with the wrong url.

The url they are indexing is:

```
1. http://www.mydomain.com/index.php?a=profile&u=john
2. http://www.mydomain.com/index.php?a=page&b=about
3. http://www.mydomain.com/index.php?a=settings&b=avatar
4. http://www.mydomain.com/index.php?a=feed
5. http://www.mydomain.com/index.php?a=feed&filter=picture
6. http://www.mydomain.com/index.php?a=post&m=32
7. http://www.mydomain.com/index.php?lang=english
8. http://www.mydomain.com/index.php?a=messages&u=john&id=4
9. http://www.mydomain.com/index.php?a=feed&logout=1
```

I need it to redirect to:

```
1. http://www.mydomain.com/john or http://www.mydomain.com/profile/john
2. http://www.mydomain.com/about or http://www.mydomain.com/page/about
3. http://www.mydomain.com/settings/avatar
4. http://www.mydomain.com/feed
5. http://www.mydomain.com/feed/picture or http://www.mydomain.com/feed/filter/picture
6. http://www.mydomain.com/message/32
7. http://www.mydomain.com/lang/english
8. http://www.mydomain.com/messages/john
9. http://www.mydomain.com/logout or http://www.mydomain.com/feed/logout
```

.htaccess isn't my forte, so any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

1. Ok, I got it working by using two method by Dan Trimper and Jon Lin. First I'm generate mod rewrite url by using Dan Trimper method. For example `http://www.mydomain.com/index.php?a=page&b=about`, so after generate it will produce the url like this `RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?a=$1&b=$2 [L]`
2. Second, after generate I'm using second method redirect url to `http://www.mydomain.com/page/about` by using Jon Lin method:

   RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index.php\?a=page&b=([^&\
   ]+) RewriteRule ^ /page/%1? [L,R=301]
3. Thank you!

Edit 2: Not working above because conflict. More accurate solution goes to this topic [.htaccess friendly URl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12538466/htaccess-friendly-url)

Comment: Look into Mod rewrite http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 1):

Try adding these rules to your htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\?a=profile&u=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /profile/%1? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\?a=page&b=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /page/%1? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\?a=settings&b=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /settings/%1? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\?a=feed&logout=1
RewriteRule ^ /feed/logout? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\?a=feed&filter=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /feed/%1? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\?a=feed
RewriteRule ^ /feed/? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\?a=feed&filter=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /feed/%1? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\?a=post&m=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /message/%1? [L,R=301]
```

etc.etc.

Comment: Thank you. The site goes to the right url but I get 404 Not Found. I need something like url rewrite or user friendly url. RewriteEngine is turn on also the module. Examples for pages, <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\?a=page&b=([^&\ ]+)
  RewriteRule ^ /page/%1? [R=301,L]

</IfModule>

Comment: @napsters if `http://www.mydomain.com/profile/john` doesn't exist, why in the **world** would you be redirecting google to those URLs?

Comment: I want trim the URL, It's something like using htaccess files for pretty URLS. Working url would be like this http://www.mydomain.com/index.php?a=profile&u=john and want to change it like OP above.

Comment: Ok I got it working using two method by Dan Trimper and you. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't too savvy with .htaccess when i first started too.

Check out this site along with the .htaccess generator - It helped me out ALOT and i think it will fix your issues.

http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/

It pre-writes the rules for your after you configure it - then copy/paste to your .htaccess file.