# y.com/?phone instead of y.com/?c=phone

Tags: php, get

I'm currently designing a small intranet for our company.

For now I'm using these links at the navigation:

```
<a href="./">Home</a>
<a href="./?c=phone">Phone</a>
<a href="./?c=xy">XY</a>
```

The page-URL looks like this: `y.com/?c=phone`
I want it to be shorter, e.g. without the `c=`

My idea was to work with true/false.
So, I won't check the variable `c` for its value, but I would check if e.g. `phone == true`.

But how can I implement this?

Comment: You can use `if(isset($_GET['phone'])` for checking if there is a parameter `phone` in your url?

Comment: Is this running on apache or IIS? You want `/phone` to to load  `index.php?c=phone`, but not expose that to user, right? If so look at rewriting URLs.

Comment: First off, none of your examples have query strings (there's no `?`). Second, it's not clear what you're aiming for here. Are you trying to make, say, `y.com/phone`?

Comment: mapek: Possible way, thank you!
user3783243 - Thanks for that approach, I'll take a deeper look at this!
Machavity - Thanks, I've edited my post. Nah, my goal is y.com/?phone which should be possible with true/or false if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

this is the simplest way I can think of:

```
if(isset($_GET['phone'])){
    //here is your page phone
}
```

now you can access this page via `y.com?phone`

Comment: This worked for me, thank you very much, even though I don't think that this is the most elegant way.

Comment: something like this could help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12538466/htaccess-friendly-url
or this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28168375/how-to-write-htaccess-rewrite-rule-for-seo-friendly-url